# uWSGI cannot find “application” using Flask and Virtualenv

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi

This is the error im getting using uwsgi on my webserver

```
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 15225)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 15230, cores: 1)
```

I used [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-authentication-to-your-app-with-flask-login) tutorial to handle logins in flask. Which is different from any flask project i used  since there is no file called app.py with the addition of

```
app = Flask(__name__)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

inside of it, which confuses me and took me now a whole day to figure out how to deploy this, but im not able to get it done. Every guide to solve this used either docker or was built up with an app.py

I am also able to get this to run by using it locally using the command
flask run in terminal. But unable to use uwsgi and adding it as a demon, it seems like this blueprint stuff is not ment to run as a standalone but is there a way to deploy this easily to a webserver?

I am trying to start it on my server with uwsgi uwsgi.ini

my uwsgi.ini

```
[uwsgi]
module = app:app
pidfile = basic_flask_template.pid
master = true
processes = 1
http-socket = :1024
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true
```

my **init**.py

```
# init.py

from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager 

# init SQLAlchemy so we can use it later in our models
db = SQLAlchemy()

app = create_app()
def create_app():

    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secretkey'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///db.sqlite'

    db.init_app(app)

    login_manager = LoginManager()
    login_manager.login_view = 'auth.login'
    login_manager.init_app(app)

    from .models import User

    @login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(user_id):
        # since the user_id is just the primary key of our user table, use it in the query for the user
        return User.query.get(int(user_id))

    # blueprint for auth routes in our app
    from .auth import auth as auth_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(auth_blueprint)

    # blueprint for non-auth parts of app
    from .main import main as main_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)

    return app
```

my main.py

```
# main.py

from flask import Blueprint, render_template
from flask_login import login_required, current_user

main = Blueprint('main', __name__)

@main.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@main.route('/profile')
@login_required
def profile():
    return render_template('profile.html', name=current_user.name)
```

my models.py

```
# models.py

from flask_login import UserMixin
from . import db

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True) # primary keys are required by SQLAlchemy
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(100))
    name = db.Column(db.String(1000))
```

and my auth.py

```
# auth.py

from flask import Blueprint, render_template, redirect, url_for, request, flash
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from flask_login import login_user, logout_user, login_required
from .models import User
from . import db

auth = Blueprint('auth', __name__)

@auth.route('/login')
def login():
    return render_template('login.html')

@auth.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login_post():
    email = request.form.get('email')
    password = request.form.get('password')
    remember = True if request.form.get('remember') else False

    user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()

    # check if user actually exists
    # take the user supplied password, hash it, and compare it to the hashed password in database
    if not user or not check_password_hash(user.password, password): 
        flash('Please check your login details and try again.')
        return redirect(url_for('auth.login')) # if user doesn't exist or password is wrong, reload the page

    # if the above check passes, then we know the user has the right credentials
    login_user(user, remember=remember)
    return redirect(url_for('main.profile'))

@auth.route('/signup')
def signup():
    return render_template('signup.html')

@auth.route('/signup', methods=['POST'])
def signup_post():

    email = request.form.get('email')
    name = request.form.get('name')
    password = request.form.get('password')

    user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first() # if this returns a user, then the email already exists in database

    if user: # if a user is found, we want to redirect back to signup page so user can try again  
        flash('Email address already exists')
        return redirect(url_for('auth.signup'))

    # create new user with the form data. Hash the password so plaintext version isn't saved.
    new_user = User(email=email, name=name, password=generate_password_hash(password, method='sha256'))

    # add the new user to the database
    db.session.add(new_user)
    db.session.commit()

    return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))

@auth.route('/logout')
@login_required
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for('main.index'))
```

Comment: `module = init:app` But you should expect an error since you defined `create_app` **after** calling it.

Comment: True i get this error.
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'init'
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***

Comment: As I see you called your module `__init__.py`. That's not a great name. It should be used in packages only and should only contain package initialization code. Choose another name and adapt your config to it!

Comment: Changed the name of the __init__.app to app.py for testing,
also changed module = app:app
run the app by uwsgi uwsgi.ini

*** Operational MODE: single process ***
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)

when trying to call the index.html on my webserver i get a 500 Internal Server error with this error in the terminal, but the no module name 'init' error is gone

*** Operational MODE: single process ***
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)

Comment: --- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors --- [pid: 14870|app: -1|req: -1/1] xxx.xx.xxx.x () {52 vars in 1022 bytes} [Mon Feb 15 09:08:44 2021] GET / => generated 21 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 83 bytes (0 switches on core 0)